# "Achshav bnei chorin"?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, song-poetry, zionism

In the widely-accepted [Passover song version of "*Avadim hayinu*"](http://www.zemereshet.co.il/song.asp?id=444), what is the origin of the stanza "*atta* (or *achshav*) *bnei chorin*"? (There is no such refrain in [the original passage in the *Haggada*](http://www.piyut.org.il/textual/859.html).) Is it (speculatively) meant as a (secular) Zionist contrast to the refrain in "*[Ha lachma anya...](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%94_-_%D7%94%D7%90_%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%90_%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%90)* of "*hashata avdei l'shana haba'ah bnei chorin*"?

Comment: Widely accepted???

Comment: @DoubleAA e.g. http://www.chabad.org/kids/article_cdo/aid/2157625/jewish/Avadim-Hayinu.htm http://image.aish.com/audio/holidays/avadim_hayinu.mp3

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is related to the concept (mentioned in [*Derush Naeh*](https://books.google.com/books?id=joDg8wxjEA0C&pg=PP117&lpg=PP117#v=onepage&q&f=false)) that this night consists of both slavery and freedom, the first half being slavery (עבדים היינו), and the second half being freedom (בני חורין).